# JS: understanding writeable as Object property attribute

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

I have recently started to play (and work) with Object.create and similar ES5 stuff. I don't quite understand the way the `writeable` attribute of an Object's property works. The spec says, that is is set to false by default, but how can I change that without using getters and setters?

Or: why works this code like it works:

**edit: this code is trash! I didn't get how getter and setter are working here yet!**

```
var ob = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    a: { 
        value: 'not save'
     },
     b: {
        value: 'value configured, but writeable',
        writeable: true
    },
    c: {
        configurable: false,
        get: function() {
            return c;
        },
        set: function(string) {
            c = string;
        }
    }
});

ob.c = 'set d the first time'; //not doing this would give us an error in the console.log line (access to ob.c)

console.log(ob.a, ob.b, ob.c); //->not save value configured, but writeable set d the first time
ob.a = 'new a';
ob.b = 'new b';
ob.c = 'new c';

console.log(ob.a, ob.b, ob.c, ob.d); //->not save value configured, but writeable new c
```

Why only ob.c is in fact writeable, but not ob.b -  or what am I doing wrong?

**edit: better code here**

```
var ob = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    a: { 
        value: 'not save',

     },
     b: {
        value: 'value configured, but writeable',
        writeable: true
    },
    c: {
        configurable: false,
        get: function() {
            return this.a; // works, but is not useful because of the naming and a is not writeable
        },
        set: function(string) {
            this.a = string; // works, but is not useful because of the naming and a is not writeable
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your getter and setter refer to a global variable named `c`, not to a property `c`.

Comment: wow, indeed the 2. -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. The standard defines the property as `writable`, not `writeable`. Fix the spelling in the `b` definition and it works perfectly:

```
 b: {
    value: 'value configured, but writeable',
    writable: true
}
```